# magento 2 call Braintree adapter method

Tags: magento2, braintree

I want to check Braintree transaction status. I am calling

```
$gateway->transaction()->search([
  Braintree_TransactionSearch::status()->is(Braintree_Transaction::SETTLED)
]);
```

in my helper but unable to do so it is giving error

> "Missing required argument $merchantId of
>   Magento\Braintree\Model\Adapter\BraintreeAdapter"

How can I call that?

Answer (score 0):

(sorry, I'd leave as a comment but I don't have those privileges yet)

Sounds like the `BraintreeAdapter` directory does not have access to your Braintree [API credentials](https://articles.braintreepayments.com/control-panel/important-gateway-credentials) located in `Braintree/Gateway/Config/Config.php` ([link](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/758ba75f7f65fe109b84f8a281b2f2e0d75faf30/app/code/Magento/Braintree/Gateway/Config/Config.php))

Can you confirm that you have added your sandbox credentials to your Magento store? You may need to instantiate the Braintree gateway in a similar fashion to [BraintreeSearchAdapter](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/758ba75f7f65fe109b84f8a281b2f2e0d75faf30/app/code/Magento/Braintree/Model/Adapter/BraintreeSearchAdapter.php)

Comment: Yes I have added the Braintree  sandbox credentials  to store.

Comment: What directory is your helper located in? Maybe that location does not have Braintree credentials loaded from a use `Braintree\Configuration` operator? I believe Braintree credentials are constructed in the `BraintreeAdapter.php` [file](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/4d4e88a89c5fa525c5ac442a1169ec71d7f8dda0/app/code/Magento/Braintree/Model/Adapter/BraintreeAdapter.php#L34)